# Convert Custom Tags Into Html Tags

Tags: php, preg-replace

My data is like this:

```
%\hCUSTOM HEADING 1%\h
%\hCUSTOM HEADING 2%\h
```

I want to convert into HTML heading:

```
<h1>CUSTOM HEADING 1</h1>
<h1>CUSTOM HEADING 2</h1>
```

How can i done this via PHP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple regular expression like this one

```
$str = '%\hCUSTOM HEADING 1%\h
%\hCUSTOM HEADING 2%\h';

echo preg_replace('/%\\\h(.*?)%\\\h/s','<h1>$1</h1>', $str);
```